# How to shift error bars along with data bars?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I am trying to create a figure with two bar graphs with bars grouped two by two.
I use `bar width` and `bar shift` to separate the bars.
My problem is that I want to add error bars to these plots but I do
not know how to make them *follow* the bars.
All I get are couples of bars (good!) but with couples of error bars
between them (awkward!).

How could I have the error bars in the middle of the *data* bars without manually shifting them?

My current attempt:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \pgfplotstableread{
    1 4   0.2  0.1
    2 4.2 0.1  0.5
    3 3.1 0.3  0.4
    4 2.5 0.25 0.35
    }\tablei

    \pgfplotstableread{
    1 3.5 0.1  0.3
    2 3.8 0.2  0.2
    3 4.0 0.25 0.25
    4 3.0 0.3  0.5
    }\tablet

    % Bar styles
    \pgfplotsset{shifti/.style={mark=no markers, bar width=4pt, bar shift=3pt}}
    \pgfplotsset{shiftt/.style={mark=no markers, bar width=4pt, bar shift=-3pt}}

    % Error styles
    \pgfplotsset{err/.style={forget plot, draw=none}} 
    \pgfplotsset{errp/.style={err, error bars/.cd,x dir=plus,  x explicit}}
    \pgfplotsset{errm/.style={err, error bars/.cd,x dir=minus, x explicit}}

    \begin{axis}[%
    /pgfplots/table/header=false,
    scale only axis,
    width=12cm,
    height=8cm,
    axis on top]

    \addplot+[xbar, shifti] table[x index=1, y index=0]{\tablei};
    \addplot+[no markers, errm] table[x index=1, y index=0, x error index=2]{\tablei};
    \addplot+[no markers, errp] table[x index=1, y index=0, x error index=3]{\tablei};

    \addplot+[xbar, shiftt] table[x index=1, y index=0]{\tablet};
    \addplot+[no markers, errm] table[x index=1, y index=0, x error index=2]{\tablet};
    \addplot+[no markers, errp] table[x index=1, y index=0, x error index=3]{\tablet};

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you strip this down a bit so that it's more minimal?

Comment: Do you mean including the data into the code? It seems fairly minimal to me.

Comment: A couple of things: 1) It would be good to have just one code block that can be copied and pasted, instead of two `tex` files and two datafiles. You can include the data in your document using the `\begin{filecontents}{<filename>}...\end{filecontents}` environment. 2) You seem to be happy to shift the bars manually (instead of just supplying `xbar` to the axis, which would take care of the offset automatically). Why don't you want to shift the error bars in the same way?

Comment: 3) Your errors seem to be different in positive and negative directions, both absolutely and relatively to the data value. Is this intentional? Could you explain the nature of these asymmetric errors (that might help with coming up with a "proper" automated solution)?

Comment: 1) I'll provide a simpler example as soon as possible.
2) Using `xbar` in the axis declaration does not give the wanted
result because I fail to prevent the (data) bars associated with the plots for the error bars to be drawn. I tried to shift manually the error bars but with no success.

Comment: 3) The asymetry is intentional : the error bars are supposed to represent the boundaries of assymetric confidence intervals.
The signs might be confusing because the data are not the length of the half confidence intervals but the position of the boundaries. This last point explain the use of
`x error expr={\thisrowno{1}-\thisrowno{2}}` in my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to position the error bars correctly is to use `yshift=<value>` to shift the error bars up or down. If you use the same `<value>` that you used for the `bar shift`, the error bars will be positioned correctly. A "proper" automatic solution in this case would require support for asymmetric error bars, which isn't currently possible with `pgfplots`. It might be worth opening a [feature request](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=224188&atid=1060659) for this.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \pgfplotstableread{
    1 4   0.2  0.1
    2 4.2 0.1  0.5
    3 3.1 0.3  0.4
    4 2.5 0.25 0.35
    }\tablei

    \pgfplotstableread{
    1 3.5 0.1  0.3
    2 3.8 0.2  0.2
    3 4.0 0.25 0.25
    4 3.0 0.3  0.5
    }\tablet

    % Bar styles
    \pgfplotsset{shifti/.style={mark=no markers, bar width=4pt, bar shift=3pt}}
    \pgfplotsset{shiftt/.style={mark=no markers, bar width=4pt, bar shift=-3pt}}

    % Error styles
    \pgfplotsset{err/.style={forget plot, draw=none}} 
    \pgfplotsset{errp/.style={err, black, error bars/.cd,x dir=plus,  x explicit}}
    \pgfplotsset{errm/.style={err, black, error bars/.cd,x dir=minus, x explicit}}

    \begin{axis}[%
    /pgfplots/table/header=false,
    scale only axis,
    width=12cm,
    height=8cm,
    axis on top]

    \addplot+[xbar, shifti] table[x index=1, y index=0]{\tablei};
    \addplot+[no markers, yshift=3pt, errm] table[x index=1, y index=0, x error index=2]{\tablei};
    \addplot+[no markers, yshift=3pt, errp] table[x index=1, y index=0, x error index=3]{\tablei};

    \addplot+[xbar, shiftt] table[x index=1, y index=0]{\tablet};
    \addplot+[no markers, yshift=-3pt, errm] table[x index=1, y index=0, x error index=2]{\tablet};
    \addplot+[no markers, yshift=-3pt, errp] table[x index=1, y index=0, x error index=3]{\tablet};

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using a macro for the shift amount makes it less cumbersome to edit. It is not perfectly `streamlined' but it does the job with limited hassle.
Support for assymetric error bars would be nice indeed.

Comment: Yes, that's a good idea. It would be ideal if the error bars could be specified as part of the actual bar plot, instead of using extra `\addplot` commands, but that will require a bit of work.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, didn't see your edit when I wrote my comment.